# download and upload stream in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have a puller application that downloads file from website. typically, it would download the entire file and then save it at some location, database or file system.
I would like to be able to stream it to other location as soon as i get the bytes from file download. so essentially, a user should be able to download the file while it is being downloaded from the actual website.

Dont know if the title is correct in that sense but you get the idea.

Comment: So, do I have this right? The user performs an action inside the application (e.g. clicks a button), which initiates a download of a resource (e.g. http://example.com/foo.txt). The application is configured for where the download goes, for example "C:\Documents\foo.txt". And now you want to instead of just saving to one place, also save it to another place, for example upload to http://example.com/bar.txt?

Comment: no. the user requests a document. request is taken up by puller console application. puller goes to respective url and downloads the document and while the puller downloads it, the download of document also starts for the user. so even though the document is not available on server, user, on requesting document will directly get the download stream from puller application while it is still streaming from target url.

Comment: assume though that user request is dispatched to puller directly and user is in the wait state while the puller goes to url and starts downloading the document. and as soon as the streaming starts for puller, it should start for the user as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Stream.CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx) method if you have access to the stream that's being downloaded.

Example:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

var request  = WebRequest.Create( "http://example.com/file.dat" );
var response = request.GetResponse();

var client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect( "127.0.0.1", 1234 );

using( var sourceStream      = response.GetResponseStream() )
using( var destinationStream = client.GetStream() )
{
    sourceStream.CopyTo( destinationStream );
}
```

The above will make a request to http://example.com/file.dat and start the download, from there it connects to an arbitrary TCP socket and copies the data from the downloading file into the TCP socket. `CopyTo` will block until all data has been read from `sourceStream` and written to `destinationStream`. The destination stream can be anything you like; `FileStream`, `MemoryStream`, or another stream returned from `WebResponse.GetResponseStream()` that represents an upload rather than a download.

Comment: This looks promising and i am going to try that. will get back to you with the results. Thanks Tony.

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the help. stream.CopyTo() is essentially downloading the stream data to create the copy stream. it means, you wouldn't get your stream in return until the middle application(puller) finished downloading the document. its sample as download the file in-memory and then streaming it out. i am looking for streaming out while streaming in. i.e. each and every bit downloaded by puller is also streamed to the consumer application.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void testdownload(stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16345];
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.FullLocalFilePath,
                    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
           fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesnt seem much different from just downloading the file and saving it in file system. Please check my comments on my question.